# How many colors can I use at one time with google map markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to use up to 31 different colored markers, all displayed on the same map at the same time. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Dr. Molle there are no limits. You will need to provide a different colored image to the icon property in the marker options as shown below.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng,map: map,title:title,icon:**IMAGE**});
```